# Quitar espacios en blanco

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Necesito que el menú ocupe todo el ancho para que no se vean esos bordes en blanco y también en la parte de arriba.
¿Qué solución sencilla existe?

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  background: #333;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
}

li ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}

.menu__item {
  flex: auto;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class=menu__item>
    <a class=menu__link href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Subitem 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class=menu__item>
    <a class=menu__link href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class=menu__item>
    <a class=menu__link href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class=menu__item>
    <a class=menu__link href="#">Item 4</a>
  </li>
  <li class=menu__item>
    <a class=menu__link href="#">Item 5</a>
  </li>
  <li class=menu__item>
    <a class=menu__link href="#">Item 6</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Al menos con el código que proporcionas, el problema es que el `<body>` tiene sus márgenes por defecto, se las pones en 0 y listo.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  background: #333;
}

ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
}

li ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}

.menu__item {
  flex: auto;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class=menu__item>
    <a class=menu__link href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Subitem 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class=menu__item>
    <a class=menu__link href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class=menu__item>
    <a class=menu__link href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class=menu__item>
    <a class=menu__link href="#">Item 4</a>
  </li>
  <li class=menu__item>
    <a class=menu__link href="#">Item 5</a>
  </li>
  <li class=menu__item>
    <a class=menu__link href="#">Item 6</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gracias, sabia que era algo simple!

Comment: @JoséIgnacio Si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada.